Issue refactoring Java if-for loop-if to if-stream

Include details about your goal

I wish to refactor the below code using Java stream()
    public String before(String input) {
        if (input.contains("to for loop")) {
            String[] splitBySpace = input.split(" ");
            for (String s : splitBySpace) {
                if (s.contains("a:")) {
                    String[] anotherSplit = s.split(":");
                    return anotherSplit[1];
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }


What I tried:

    public String after(String input) {
        if (input.contains("to for loop")) {
            String[] splitBySpace = input.split(" ");
            return Arrays.stream(splitBySpace)
.filter(oneSplit -> oneSplit.contains("a:"))
.map(oneContains -> oneContains.split(";")[1])
.findFirst();
        }
        return null;
    }


Issue:

Unfortunately, the refactored method is giving an Optional of String, instead of the String, cannot compile.

Question?

What is the correct refactored method using Java stream?

Unpack the Optional via get or  orElse.

check the documentation of Optional: e.g. orElse |-| no sure if I like such a mixed solution (non-stream and stream)

findFirst returns an Optional to represent the fact that the stream might not contain elements, in which case the returned Optional is empty. The imperative code would return null when the for loop did not find any strings that contain a:. Therefore, you can use orElse(null) to convert the Optional<String> to a String, where null is returned if the Optional is empty.
return Arrays.stream(splitBySpace)
        .filter(oneSplit -> oneSplit.contains("a:"))
        .map(oneContains -> oneContains.split(";")[1])
        .findFirst().orElse(null);

Also consider converting this whole method to a method call chain, and return an Optional<String> in the end, instead of a String that can be null.
public Optional<String> after(String input) {
    // use ofNullable to gracefully handle a null input
    return Optional.ofNullable(input)
            // this filter is analogous to the if statement
            .filter(x -> x.contains("to for loop"))
            .stream()
            .flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x.split(" ")))
            .filter(oneSplit -> oneSplit.contains("a:"))
            .map(oneContains -> oneContains.split(";")[1])
            .findFirst();
}


In this case the stream seems correct, however the findFirst() method has an Optional return type.
What you can do is:

Check if the method has not found what you are looking for by using the isEmpty() method, and throwing an exception.
Use the orElse() method to handle the case where the String is not found.


Sounds quite good, do you have a snippet?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
